# SQL command tallies totals into 2nd table

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL command that SUMS up incidents from TableA and imports the totals into TableB. Then another command that calculates the totals from B and INSERTS INTO TableC. Is it possible to include in TableC the names of those that have the recorded incidents? (Right now it only SUMS up totals and reports as a whole with no names)

I'll give some examples:

### TableB

Day 1

Name | Incidents

Tim | 1

Frank | 2

Jay | 1

Day 2

Name | incidents

Tim | 1

Frank | 1

Jay | 1

### TableC

Name | Incidents

Tim | 2

Frank | 3

Jay | 2

TableC continues to record data while TableB will be dropped and re recorded daily.

Here is the SQL command to fill TableB:

```
SELECT [Name], SUM(TableAColumnA) AS TableBColumnB INTO TableB FROM TableA GROUP BY [Name]
```

Here is the SQL I've tried to populate TableC:

```
INSERT INTO TableC(ImportDate, DayofData, Name, ColumnBTalbeB)
SELECT GETDATE() AS ImportDate, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DayofData,
    (SELECT SUM(ColumnBTableB) FROM TableB);
```

What this does is give NULL value to Name and calculate all incidents recorded in TableB.ColumnB. I basically need to show the names of those that had contributed to the total of incidents into TableC. TableC looks like this:

### TableC

Name | Incidents | ImportDate | DayofData

NULL | 4 | today's date/time | yesterday's date/time

Was hoping to do something like this.

### TableC

Name | incidents | totalincidents | importdate | dayofdata

Tim | 1 | 4 | today's date/tome | yesterday's date/time

Is this possible or do I need to have it calculate into a whole separate table entirely? or just wishful thinking gone too far?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

If you could do without TotalIncidents, you would use `GROUP BY`:

```
INSERT INTO TableC(ImportDate, DayofData, Name, Incidents)
    SELECT GETDATE() AS ImportDate, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DayofData, Name, Incidents
        FROM (SELECT Name, SUM(ColumnBTableB) AS Incidents
            FROM TableB
            GROUP BY Name);
```

Since `TotalIncidents` can be obtained from other data by query:

```
SELECT SUM(Incidents) AS TotalIncidents
    FROM TableC
    WHERE DayOfData BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '1/24/2016', 101)
                    AND CONVERT(datetime, '1/25/2016', 101);
```

Do you really need to store `TotalIncidents` as a column? It just adds complexity.

Comment: Hey Sam. To be honest breaking them into 3 tables will take you nowhere near to being a database or sql expert. Have it on 1 table and record all incidents there referrencing the personid. This will make your life easier.

Comment: I can assure you I'm in no way claiming to be SQL expert. However this was the way I had thought was the only way. Do you have an suggestions or sample SQL Commands that can make all this transition into 1 table? I'd be happy give my full attention to your samples.

Comment: @S. Rojak, I will give this a try. As far as the TotalIncidents Column, not really I mean it's lower numbers anyway so no need for it to do the math also, I mainly need it to record the sum and export to TableC with the name and just continue to record until I drop the table or reset it essentially.

Comment: @S. Rojak, So I have tried what you suggestion. Running into an error stating:
Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Comment: I corrected the query syntax. I should note that `DayOfData` is also redundant; as currently defined, you could obtain this at query time. The subselect is to simplify the GROUP BY, but this query can be expressed without the subselect provided you include the first two expressions (not column aliases) in the GROUP BY.

Comment: sorry for getting back at this so late, but it still has not worked, same error. I think I will be going at a different approach where I get the names and incidents only and just join into TableC